# How to count comparisons and swaps in quicksort?

Tags: java, quicksort

```
public class IntQuickSorter
{
   public static int numOfComps = 0,
                     numOfSwaps = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      // Create an int array with test values.
      int[] values = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,  6 };
      //int[] values = { 5, 1, 3, 6, 4, 2 };
      //int[] values = { 5, 7, 2, 8, 9, 1 };

        System.out.println("\n\nQuick Sort:");

      // Display the array's contents.
      System.out.println("\nOriginal order: ");
      for (int element : values)
         System.out.print(element + " ");

      // Sort the array.
      quickSort(values);

      //System.out.println("\n\nNumber of comps = " + numOfComps);
      //System.out.println("Number of swaps = " + numOfSwaps);

      // Display the array's contents.
      System.out.println("\nSorted order: ");
      for (int element : values)
         System.out.print(element + " ");

      System.out.println();
   }

   public static void quickSort(int array[])
   {
      doQuickSort(array, 0, array.length - 1);
      System.out.println("\n\nNumber of comps = " + numOfComps);
       System.out.println("Number of swaps = " + numOfSwaps);
   }

   private static void doQuickSort(int array[], int start, int end)
   {
      int pivotPoint;

      if (start < end)
      {
         numOfComps++;

         // Get the pivot point.
         pivotPoint = partition(array, start, end);

         // Sort the first sub list.
         doQuickSort(array, start, pivotPoint - 1);

         // Sort the second sub list.
         doQuickSort(array, pivotPoint + 1, end);
      }
   }

   private static int partition(int array[], int start, int end)
   {
      int pivotValue;    // To hold the pivot value
      int endOfLeftList; // Last element in the left sub list.
      int mid;           // To hold the mid-point subscript

      // Find the subscript of the middle element.
      // This will be our pivot value.
      mid = (start + end) / 2;

      // Swap the middle element with the first element.
      // This moves the pivot value to the start of 
      // the list.
      swap(array, start, mid);

      // Save the pivot value for comparisons.
      pivotValue = array[start];

      // For now, the end of the left sub list is
      // the first element.
      endOfLeftList = start;

      // Scan the entire list and move any values that
      // are less than the pivot value to the left
      // sub list.
      for (int scan = start + 1; scan <= end; scan++)
      {

         if (array[scan] < pivotValue)
         {
            endOfLeftList++;
            swap(array, endOfLeftList, scan);

                numOfSwaps ++;
         }
         numOfComps++;
      }

      // Move the pivot value to end of the
      // left sub list.
      swap(array, start, endOfLeftList);

      // Return the subscript of the pivot value.
      return endOfLeftList;
   }

   private static void swap(int[] array, int a, int b)
   {
      int temp;

         temp = array[a];
         array[a] = array[b];
         array[b] = temp;
    }
}
```

How do I code this quicksort program in Java to count the number of comparisons and the number of swaps? Where I have the swap code now, it counts swaps even with a sorted array of numbers and it shouldn't. And is the comparison code in the right place? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you try to place a counter number into `swap()`, and increment it's value every time, it's called? The same way, you should create a `compare()` function, where you compare two ints, and increment a global variable each time, it called.

Comment: @Nagy Hi Nagy, I'm a newbie at computer programming; I have less than a year under my belt in it. Yes, I placed the swap counter "numOfSwaps ++;" into swap() and it counted 3 swaps with a sorted array of 6 numbers and it shouldn't count swaps in a sorted array. How do I code it to fix it? How do I code a compare() method? I've included my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where I have the swap code now, it counts swaps even with a sorted array of numbers and it shouldn't.

That's not quite accurate.  A sorted array **will** have some swaps with quicksort, that's how the pivoting and partitioning works.  Here's an animation of a typical quicksort using a sorted list.  [Animation](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/d8e15a0ab7f85818a5bd) [gist](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/d8e15a0ab7f85818a5bd)

[image: quicksort-on-sorted]

Also, remove this comparison:

```
if (start < end)
      {
         numOfComps++;
```

Because that is not a "key comparison" of two things in the array, just of your indices.
Other than that, your comparisons and swaps look to be in the right place.

Comment: That's a really cool animation gist program. Did you create that yourself? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I did not create the original program (although I forked it and set it up with mergesort and a few others).  As I [cited above](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/d8e15a0ab7f85818a5bd) a user by the name of @mbostock created it.  All of his gists (which are just small snippets of code hosted on GitHub) are at https://gist.github.com/mbostock

Answer (score -1):

You can use following method http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List- 
As far as I remember it uses quick sort algorith 
When you implement you own Comparator then you can increment counter when comparator is invoked (number of comparisons) and increment other counter when one value is bigger then other (then swap occurs).

Comment: No.  Collections.sort is not QuickSort.  It's something called [TimSort](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listsort.txt).  From the [Java 7 docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html): `Implementation note: This implementation is a stable, adaptive, iterative mergesort that requires far fewer than n lg(n) comparisons when the input array is partially sorted, while offering the performance of a traditional mergesort when the input array is randomly ordered.`

Comment: But, if you wanted to count comparisons of the built in sort and compare it to something like QuickSort, you could call [Collections.sort(list, myComparator)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) and pass in your own Comparator that has a simple int that increments on every call.  I'm not sure how you could count swaps in a similar way though...

Comment: Swap operation is done after compare if needed - depends on compare result